# Android could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ' classpath'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is like the first time im using Android Studio, and when I try to run the app It shows me the following error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'PickApp'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+.
     Required by:
         :PickApp:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
```

Build.grandle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have clear network access to the jcenter.bintray.com DNS? It seems that you're not reaching it. Could you include your build.gradle DSL? Is there any particular reason or constraint for that special configuration? Why not to use the main Google repositories for Android Gradle plugin?

Comment: build.grandle has been added

Comment: Could you try to replace all your repositories references for: repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/uandroid/tools/build/gradle/'
    }
}

Comment: That looks like your parent build.gradle. Do you have any special buildscript configuration in for your module? Maybe you have already fixed though.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?